# What is causing my model to overfit?

Tags: neural-networks

I am using a standard, well-known model(untrained) to classify between LabelA and NotLabelA.

I randomly create training and testing data with exactly 50% LabelA and 50% NotLabelA.

The standard model includes dropout layers, but after 30 epochs in training I get low loss and high accuracy, but in test, the loss starts to increase and accuracy remains around 0.5.

Test loss increasing with training loss decrease is usually sign of overfitting. BUT I have created my sample data very carefully, and model has dropouts.

What else might be causing this?

Comment: Your question is "What else might be causing this?" but it's not clear what you mean by "else." Would it be fair to rephrase your question as "What is causing my model to overfit?"

Comment: How many observations does your training data contain and how many parameters/weights are you estimating? Note that dropout reduces overfitting, its not eliminating it.

Comment: Good point! I made the change

Comment: Training data has approx 1,500 combined LabelA and NotLabelA. From summary: Total params: 28,040,483
Trainable params: 28,040,483

Comment: so you have given the answer to your question: Your model architecture is too complex.

Comment: What should ratio between data and parameters be as a maximum?

Comment: What kind of neural net are you using? Is transfer learning an option, i.e. taking a pre-trained model and just use your data to modify the last couple of layers?

Comment: No. It is trained from scratch

Comment: You should not copy a model that was successful in another scenario; you should start with a model that is applicable to your situation. Draw inspiration from the model you saw as successful and apply it to a model that fits to the size of your data. Simple is better than complex.

Answer (score 4):

In many cases, the reason for overfitting is too little data, and very complicated model. If you are using Neural Network, even with drop out, it is very easy to have millions of parameters.

This means you can fit the training data perfectly. And such model will fail on some data **other than training data**.

You said you are simulating data, so, I assume you many not have the computational power to simulate the data large enough for the model.

Try following things:

1. use simple neural network with 1 hidden layer, and few hidden unit.
2. you can forget about the regularization if you are using this simple model.

Run this model again to see the results.

Comment: The reason I am using this particular model is because it is very successful in another field. I suspect I need to create more data - which is not really possible...

Comment: How much data would I realistically need to be able to use a model with 28 Million parameters?

Comment: @ManInMoon You'll probably need the same amount of data as was used to train the model in the other field. Using more aggressive [tag:regularization] or reducing the parameter count could reduce the amount of training data that you need.

Comment: Well, that was trained on a million images! I only have 1.5K!

Comment: @ManInMoon What did you expect? A complex model trained with lots of data and tuned regularization generalizes well. If you don't have much data, overfitting is a very real problem. So the answer to your question "What is causing my model to overfit?" is "**You don't have very much training data.**"

Comment: @Sycorax You could be right! However, when I introduce something into my images (I create them from data) that I KNOW has informational value - then the fit works as expected. I guess what this means is that when I get testing loss rising - there is no informational value in my image...